# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: node.js, angularjs, passport-twitter

I have seen this issue multiple times been posted on forum, but working out with those solutions hasn't helped.

I am building MEAN stack app using PassportJS to allow login with Twitter.

```
angular.module('HomeCtrl', []).controller('HomeController', function($scope,$http) {

$scope.tagline = 'To the moon and back!';   
$scope.twit = function() {
    console.log("twitter button clicked");
    $http.get("/auth/twitter")
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    //$window.location.href = '/auth/twitter';
}});
```

My route.js in server has

```
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter', { scope : 'email' }));
```

Now when the twitter redirects to the app, the server redirect doesnt work because of CORS issue, which I am able to understand. To fix this

I have tried following

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
  next();
});
```

but still this doesn't work. After reading more on web my understanding is that twitter doesn't send the header-origin ,and since its a redirect so node.js server doesn't have control on the response it receives which can be sent to the browser back .

At this stage I am not sure how to proceed. Please advise

As per comment : Here is the  response of twitter callback

```
Request URL:https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=l8OKcAvqr3QLrlCroweGgByvvhXfSmIiqhvRgGqML6c
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
oauth_token:l8OKcAvqr3QLrlCroweGgByvvhXfSmIiqhvRgGqML6c
```

Comment: Give more details of the specific request that is failing for you. Go to your browser and check the error and check the request to see what Origin header field the browser added to your request. Come back with those details and maybe we can help.

Comment: That request is not to your server. That request is for a twitter server. Did you program your CORS support code in the server running API.twitter.com? Because otherwise this makes no sense. Your CORS code goes in the server attending your request, not in the server that served your content.

Comment: I'm having similar issue. Any resolution?

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that twitter doesn't set the CORS headers (not your own node server). You can't get around that. 
So you could use a simple ink `<a href="/auth/twitter"></a>` instead of the $http.get or a `$window.location.href`. 
Just be aware that you won't have your http interceptors applied in that case, so you potentially need to pass some query parameters instead.